# Let, $f \in \mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ then $ \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin(nx)f(x) ~ dx = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Since, $f \in \mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$,  there exists a sequence of cont. functions, $(g_k)_{k \ge 1}$, with compact support such that:
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \|f - g_k\|_{\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})} = 0. \ $$

Let, $\psi$ be  cont. function with compact support, $K$. Then there exists a $r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K \subseteq ~  [-\pi r,\pi r].$ Let,
$$M = \sup_{x \in [-\pi r, \pi r]} \psi(x).$$

We have that,
$$ \int^{\pi r}_{-\pi r}|\psi(x) \sin(nx)| \le M\int^{\pi r}_{-\pi r}|\sin(nx)| = 0, ~ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

So we have that,
$$\| f\sin(nx)\|_{\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})} \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)\sin(nx) - g_k(x)\sin(nx)| ~ dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}}|g_k(x)\sin(nx)| ~ dx. $$
So then we obtain,
$$\| f\sin(nx)\|_{\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}   \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x) - g_k(x)| ~ dx  + \int_{\mathbb{R}}|g_k(x)\sin(nx)| ~ dx. $$
We then let $n$ go to infinity on both sides of the previous inequality in order to obtain:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\| f\sin(nx)\|_{\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}   \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x) - g_k(x)| ~ dx  + 0. $$
Then we let $k$ go to infinity on both sides of the previous inequality in order to obtain:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\| f\sin(nx)\|_{\mathbb{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})}   \le 0 .  $$
Therefore,

$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(nx)f(x) ~ dx  = 0. $$

Is this proof correct, thanks?

Comment: You wrote that the integral of $\int_{-\pi r}^{\pi r}| \sin(nx)| dx = 0$ but $|\sin|$ is a non-negative function.

Comment: I agree with @DionelJaime ... the theorem says that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \sin(nx)\;dx = 0$$  But it is certainly not the case that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} \big|f(x) \sin(nx)\big|\;dx = 0$$ the theorem definitely relies on positive and negative parts canceling.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f$ is defined by $\widehat{f}(t)=\int e^{-2\pi I t\cdot y} f(y)\,dy$.
Notice that since $e^{\pi i} = -1$ then
$$ \widehat{f}(y) =  - \int  f(x)e^{-2 \pi i  \big( x  + \tfrac{y}{2|y|^2} \big) \cdot y } \, dx= - \int f \big( x - \tfrac{y}{2|y|^2} \big) e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot y}\, dx.$$
 Hence,$$ 2\widehat{f}(y)  = \int  \Big( f(x)  - f  \big( x  - \tfrac{y}{2|y|^2} \big) \Big) e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot y}\, dx,$$ whence  $2\big|\widehat{f}(y)\big| \leq\|f- \tau_{h}f\|_1$ with  $h = \tfrac{y}{2|y|^2}$.  Then $\widehat{f}(y) \rightarrow 0$ as $|y| \rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I see my mistakes now, thanks.

Comment: Your problem follows by taking the sine part of $e^{2\pi it\cdot y}=\cos(2\pi t\cdot y)+i\sin(2\pi t\cdot y)$

Comment: You seem to be switching between $n \to 0$ and $\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\f}{\tilde f}\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}\newcommand{\d}{\ {\mathrm d}}\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\md}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$The issues with your proof have been pointed out. Namely, you do not have the integral of the absolute value of $\sin$ as $0$.

I assume you mean $n \to \infty$ and that the limit is via integers but I prove the result for the general limit via positive reals. I imitate the proof that the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function vanishes at $\infty$.

---

Define $$\f(\xi) := \int_{\R} \sin(\xi x)f(x) \d x \tag{1}$$
for $\xi > 0$.
Since $\sin(\theta + \pi) = -\sin(\theta)$, we have
$$\f(\xi) = -\int_{\R}\sin\left(\xi\left(x + \frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)\right)f(x) \d x.$$
A simple change of variable gives
$$\tilde f(\xi) = -\int_{\R}\sin(\xi x)f\left(x - \frac{\pi}{\xi}\right) \d x. \tag{2}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives us
$$2\f(\xi) = \int_{\R}\sin(\xi x)\left[f(x) - f\left(x - \frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)\right] \d x.$$
Take absolute values to get
$$\md{2\f(\xi)} \leqslant \int_{\R}\md{f(x) - f\left(x - \frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)} \d x.$$

Now, if $f$ is a continuous function with compact support, then we can use DCT to let $\xi \to \infty$ and conclude that $\tilde f(\xi) \to 0$.
After that, assume $f$ to be an arbitrary $L^1$ function and let $\e > 0$ be arbitrary. Then, there exists a compactly supported continuous function $g$ such that $$\|f - g\|_{L^1} < \e.$$
From that, conclude the following for all $\xi > 0$:
\begin{align}
\md{\f(\xi)} & \leqslant \md{\f(\xi) - \tilde g(\xi)} + \md{\tilde g(\xi)} \\ 
&= \md{\widetilde{f - g}(\xi)} + \md{\tilde g(\xi)} \\ 
&\leqslant \|f - g\|_{L^1} + \md{\tilde g(\xi)} \\
&\leqslant \e + \md{\tilde g(\xi)}.
\end{align}
Thus, using the result about compactly supported continuous functions, we see that
$$\limsup_{\xi \to \infty} \md{\f(\xi)} \leqslant \e.$$
Since $\e > 0$ was arbitrary, we are done!